# Передача данных от Android-приложения на сервер

Tags: java, android, сервер

Кафедра попросила предоставить обзор на все возможные способы передачи данных, я знаю только Google Cloud Messaging , IMEI , JMS , C2DM .

Знаете ли вы еще какие-либо технологии передачи данных(начиная от коротких сообщений и заканчивая мультимедийным контентом)?

Comment: Передачи данных откуда куда?

Comment: Google Cloud Messaging , IMEI , JMS , C2DM... sms, email, icq, skype =)

Comment: [json][1], [protobuf][2] или я не понял вопроса ?


  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON
  [2]: http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/

Answer (score 2):

**Google Cloud Messaging** это новый способ организовать пуш. С сервера точно прислать можно, это наследник C2DM. А вот можно ли с клиента на сервер слать - не знаю.

**IMEI** это просто идентификатор телефона (точнее - его радиомодуля - [wiki](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMEI)). Передать не получится ничего.

**JMS** это вообще jvm'овское и я не уверен, что оно на dalvik будет работать.

**C2DM** - тут сообщения от сервера к клиенту. Хотя есть недокументированный способ от клиента к серверу (используется GoogleTalk, для широких масс недоступен).

Но если посмотреть, то есть два основных способа - TCP/UDP и все, что базируется на них ( в том числе и C2DM, HTTP, FTP) и sms (да, да, обычные смски). Хотя еще можно и голосовые сообщения притянуть, но в новомодных сетях (LTE к примеру), голос передается по tcp/udp.

Есть ещё всякие `SCTP, RTP`, но это уже немножко экзотика.

Рекомендую почитать [Сетевая модель OSI](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_OSI) и выбрать подходящие:)

Comment: Я передаю и получаю данные через IMEI ))

Comment: 7 уровней ОСИ до сих пор вспоминаю)

Comment: И как Вы передаете данные через IMEI ?

Comment: @Автостопом_до_Рая IMEI - это просто набор цифр. через набор цифр нельзя передать данные, так же, как и через, например, название программы. Это не канал передачи данных, это просто число.

Answer (score 0):

SOAP, REST, всякие MQ (MQTT, RabbitMQ, ActivMQ)
вообще не совсем понятно нужно разные протоколы но реализованные поверх например одного http или нужно прям реально разно как например (SMS и HTTP)